# Place cursor at end of text input did not work on some cases

Tags: css, html, contenteditable

i add an icon next to a div whose contenteditable property is set to true. Until i add this icon, contenteditable was working perfectly (i was able to edit and cursor was placed to end of the entry upon pressing end key). But with addition of this icon, i am still able to edit the value but the cursor is not placed at end of entry upon pressing end key. Any idea what i might be doing wrong here.

```
<ul>
 <li>
     <div name="value" class="divinline" contenteditable="true">Test1</div>
        <a class="removelink" onclick="this.parentNode.parentNode.removeChild(this.parentNode);">
            <img src="/../images/remove_grey.png" alt="X" ></a>
  </li>
 </ul>
```

CSS

```
.divinline {
     display: inline;
 }
a.removelink {
   float: none !important;
   border: medium none !important;
   display: inline !important;
}
```

Comment: I've loaded your code into a JSFIddle [Here](https://jsfiddle.net/ngnu6wco/) and the "end" key seems to work perfectly fine. Perhaps there was another change you made at the same time that is causing the error? Have you tried removing the <a></a> element again and seeing whether the problem is still there?

Comment: Hi Stanley, I forget to mention i use Firefox and end key did not work there, do u think it could be  a browser related issue?

Comment: So you don't see it as an issue in Chrome or IE? If that's the case you're unlikely to be doing something "wrong", it may be an issue with the browser. Are you using the latest browser version? Did you try removing the link and seeing whether it started working again like I suggested?

Comment: Yes when i remove the link, end key works even in firefox (version 42.0). In chrome it works along with the link,.